# Chinese characters appear in vscode context menu. How do I get rid of them?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VS Code (version 1.49.1) on my Ubuntu 18.04.

I just noticed this that all of a sudden I see Chinese characters appear when I right click on folders or files in the project files space on the left.

[image]

Not sure what's causing this or what that text even means. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Probably one of the extensions you have installed does this.

Comment: Yeah, checks out. See my answer below.

Comment: "React Native Tools by Microsoft" is the culprit plugin.

Answer (score 3):

As @HolyBlackCat commented above, it was one of the extensions. I didn't have the patience to figure out which extension it was, but I went ahead and removed some unused extensions and it worked. That one odd Chinese menu entry is now gone.

The culprit is one of these three extensions:-

1. Binary by asurance
2. React Native Tools by Microsoft
3. React-Native/React/Redux snippets for es6/es7 by EQuimper

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: I had this same problem and removing Binary extension fixed this

Answer (score 0):

"React Native Tools by Microsoft" is the culprit plugin! I just disabled it and all good :)